# How can i make a uilabel rotate around a point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uilabel, point

For example: i have 4 uilabel: label1 label2 label3 label4, at the same position, i make label2 around point1 rotate 90∘,label3 around point1 rotate 180∘,label4 around point1 rotate 270∘, after rotation, the 4 label form a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Add four label one upon another. And then:

```
[label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

Adjust -M_PI / 2 this part to achieve other rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the labels to their subview using the same frames.

Change the anchor point of each view's layer to something like (0.5, 3.0). This changes the point that transforms are done around. The anchor point is measured in *unit space*, meaning 1.0 is the full width of the view, and 1.0 is the full height. The default anchor point is (0.5,0.5).

Apply the different rotation transforms to each label. They will now form a square centered on the anchor point.

If you want to make the text form an actual circle, then labels aren't the answer, you need to look at core text.

Comment: my code like that self.label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);[self.label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];when i run the project, the label only text rotated, and it rotated around the center not the anchorPoint i set.

Comment: Try by using the layer transform: `self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2,0.0,0.0,1.0);`